# problem in accessing public server

Tags: android, web-services

I'm working on android platform and am facing some problem in fetching data from public server. The same application works well for local server. So let me know if there are any changes in eclipse setting or some other solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be hard to answer without additional information.
Any chance for seeing some code?
What exactly are you trying to do?

Anyway, if it works locally, sounds like N/W problems. Can you ping the remote server?